# How do I change the colspan dynamically on page using only JS or CSS.

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have an 3rd-party application served page that I need to hide/show some of the content. I have a series of CSS styles (prefixed by '_' e.g. _budget, _runrates, _forecast etc) that format the sections.

The classes which affect the whole section work as desired but I need to also hide columns within each section ie. hide/show budgets, forecasts etc

For example, changing the __budget to _budget will 'hide' columns. Changing __runrates to _runrate will hide the runrate section.

I'd like to be able to do this via JS (or JQuery) or perhaps there's a CSS combination I've haven't tried.

I've isolated the section of the dynamically created page in the JSFiddle below.

```
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT0" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_0" e="1" l="0" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7"></td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT1 _month _spacer" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_1" e="1" l="1" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7"> </td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT2 _month" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_2" e="1" l="2" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7" colspan="7">May 2016</td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT9 _quarter _spacer" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_9" e="1" l="9" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7"> </td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT10 _quarter" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_10" e="1" l="10" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7" colspan="7">May QTD 2016</td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT6 _year _spacer" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_17" e="1" l="17" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7"> </td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT7 _yearly" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_18" e="1" l="18" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7" colspan="7">May YTD 2016</td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT3 _spacer _year" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_25" e="1" l="25" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7"> </td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT4 _year  _fullyearcol" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_26" e="1" l="26" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7" colspan="5">2016</td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT9 _spacer _runrates" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_31" e="1" l="31" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7"> </td>
      <td class="mPTHCT PTRHCT10 mPTLC PTLC _runrates _runratescol" id="htl_saw_15433_7_1_32" e="1" l="32" s="-1" cid="saw_15433_7" colspan="5">Run Rates</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/damiani8/88xn4tpz/9/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking to just change colspan or hide cells AND change colspan?  I am not sure if you can set a cell with display=none and have colspan cover it.  Sounds kinda messy to me.  You can delete a cell and adjust colspan, I know that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example with jQuery

```
$("#htl_saw_15433_7_1_2").attr('colspan',3);
```

I haven't heard about CSS way for that.

You can also set "display:none" for items you do not want to show (with `.css("display","none")`).

Comment: That id is dynamic, the colspan needs to be updated with the number of visible columns in the lower section.

Comment: @DamianArnold iterate over all children, check display of none and for those that have attr colspan and display non none update colspan... for me it is a little bit ugly approach, tho

Comment: I know @laser but I'm limited as the page is created by a 3rd party app. dynamically each and every time. I was thinking that a count of section css class names by section - those tagged with the 'hidden' CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector("#htl_saw_15433_7_1_2").colSpan = "3"` // or some other value from a variable/calculation.

`document.getElementById("#htl_saw_15433_7_1_2").colSpan = "3";` // also this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).